# Android Unit Tests and Database Handler

Tags: java, android, sqlite, unit-testing

I'm a little lost on how to properly test the database of my Android application. 
I have my Database Handler which extends SQLiteOpenHelper. Some solutions advise mocking this class, but how will that get me a separate instance of my database? I also see the suggestion to use an [in-memory SQLite database](https://attakornw.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/using-in-memory-sqlite-database-in-android-tests/) but that seems like a lot of unnecessary juggling...

How should I be testing my database? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did for my database library:

```
public class TestDatabaseManager extends AndroidTestCase {

    HrSuiteDatabaseManager dbm;

    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        RenamingDelegatingContext rdcontext = new RenamingDelegatingContext(getContext(), "test_");
        dbm = new HrSuiteDatabaseManager(rdcontext);
        dbm.registerTableAccess(new EmployeeAccess());
    }

    public void testInsertion() {
        EmployeeAccess ea = dbm.getEmployeeAccess();
        ea.insert(createEmployee(0));

        List<Employee> emps = ea.getAll();
        assertEquals(1, emps.size());

        assertEmployee(emps.get(0), 0);
    }
}
```

The key here is the class `RenamingDelegatingcontext` that will create the database file with specified prefix.

I have `HrSuiteDatabaseManager` that is derived from `SQLiteOpenHelper`. I  instantiate it using `RenamingDelegatingcontext` and use it in my test cases as usual.